# MySQL keeps crashing in Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, mysql, crash

Every few hours, MySQL crashes on my Digital Ocean Ubuntu 12.04 machine. Below is the errors I am seeing in my MySQL error log. I thought it was a memory issue, so I added a swap, but that didn't fix it.

```
140806 11:58:57 [Warning] Using unique option prefix myisam-recover instead of myisam-recover-options is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use the full name instead.
140806 11:58:57 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
140806 11:58:57 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
140806 11:58:57 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
140806 11:58:57 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3.4
140806 11:58:58 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
InnoDB: mmap(137363456 bytes) failed; errno 12
140806 11:58:58 InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
140806 11:58:58 InnoDB: Fatal error: cannot allocate memory for the buffer pool
140806 11:58:58 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error.
140806 11:58:58 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
140806 11:58:58 [ERROR] Unknown/unsupported storage engine: InnoDB
140806 11:58:58 [ERROR] Aborting

140806 11:58:58 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete
```

Here is a look at my memory (free -m):

```
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:          2003        384       1619          0         12         50
-/+ buffers/cache:        321       1682
Swap:          511         18        493
```

Can someone please help me figure out how I can stop this from happening?

Comment: error 12 is `ENOMEM`, ie. "Out of memory" (see `mmap(1)`); in other words, it does seem to be a memory problem... When are you running your `free` command? After MySQL already crashed? It makes sense that you have lots of free memory then, since MySQL has stopped and isn't taking it up any more...

Comment: Should I increase my SWAP?

Comment: Could you post also your `/etc/mysql/my.cnf` file ?

Answer (score 2):

The error is in the log:

```
Fatal error: cannot allocate memory for the buffer pool
```

As a quick solution you have here 2 options:

1. add more RAM to the server, or
2. decrease the value of `innodb-buffer-pool` size in the config file:

   `innodb_buffer_pool_size = 10M`