# MySQL gradually taking up more and more memory

Tags: apache2, mysql, ram, crash, wordpress

Just to start with, I have read the following threads and they do not help:

[Optimising MySQL settings - mysqld running out of memory](https://askubuntu.com/questions/422037/optimising-mysql-settings-mysqld-running-out-of-memory)
[MySQL Server keep shutting down](https://askubuntu.com/questions/581104/mysql-server-keep-shutting-down)
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12114746/mysqld-service-stops-once-a-day-on-ec2-server
[MySQL keeps crashing in Ubuntu 12.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/507604/mysql-keeps-crashing-in-ubuntu-12-04)

I am running MySQL, Apache, Wordpress on Amazon EC2. I started with a t2.nano and migrated to a t2.medium as MySQL kept crashing.

As I learned from the above threads, this is about MySQL running out of RAM.  A t2.medium has 4Gb of RAM.

No crashes since the upgrade, however, I set up a Perl script to run every 20 minutes, collect memory stats by running "free -m", and these are plotted below:

[RAM increases over time](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RqFvz.png)

As you can see, over time, the amount of RAM being taken up is increasing, and we can all see where this is going to end - a crash.

So I ran:

ps -e -o pid,vsz,comm= | sort -n -k 2

And the bottom of the resulting table is:

```
25827 382080 apache2
25828 382080 apache2
25829 382080 apache2
25830 382080 apache2
25831 382080 apache2
25832 382080 apache2
25821 382564 apache2
25816 382580 apache2
25826 382580 apache2
25811 392876 apache2
23868 393828 apache2
23797 393832 apache2
23858 393840 apache2
23859 393852 apache2
25717 393932 apache2
25797 394080 apache2
23867 396320 apache2
23753 397012 apache2
 1102 1745780 mysqld
```

So both apache2 and mysqld are taking up the vast majority of my memory, but why?  There is no correlation with load on the server - my wordpress blog is getting < 1000 hits per day.

What is causing this?  Any help greatly appreciated

Mick